# How should I scroll my page on mobile devices?

Tags: javascript

I have a slider that scrolls when user uses scroll wheel, but on mobile phone it doesn't work. How i should solve this? I used jQuery scroll() but it is not working. Help please.
The slider is pretty much simple, and totaly fine on computer, but it is not working on my phone
What should i use? What method?

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  var curPage = 1;
  var numOfPages = $(".skw-page").length;
  var animTime = 1000;
  var scrolling = false;
  var pgPrefix = ".skw-page-";

  function pagination() {
    scrolling = true;

    $(pgPrefix + curPage).removeClass("inactive").addClass("active");
    $(pgPrefix + (curPage - 1)).addClass("inactive");
    $(pgPrefix + (curPage + 1)).removeClass("active");

    setTimeout(function() {
      scrolling = false;
    }, animTime);
  };

  function navigateUp() {
    if (curPage === 1) return;
    curPage--;
    pagination();
  };

  function navigateDown() {
    if (curPage === numOfPages) return;
    curPage++;
    pagination();
  };


  $(document).on("mousewheel DOMMouseScroll", function(e) {
    if (scrolling) return;
    if (e.originalEvent.wheelDelta > 0 || e.originalEvent.detail < 0) {
      navigateUp();
    } else { 
      navigateDown();
    }
  });


  $(document).on("keydown", function(e) {
    if (scrolling) return;
    if (e.which === 38) {
      navigateUp();
    } else if (e.which === 40) {
      navigateDown();
    }
  });

});
```